# standalone package wrongly claims sub-preamble of a subfile changed if used with \file_input:n instead of \input

Tags: expl3, standalone, preamble

As shown by the following MCE, the `standalone` package loaded with its `subpreambles` option gives the expected result with `\input`, but not with `\file_input:n` when the input file has a non empty preamble. In such a case, the content’s of `subfile2.tex` isn't inserted and following warning is emitted:

> Package standalone Warning: Sub-preamble of file 'test.tex' has changed. Content will be ignored. Please rerun LaTeX! on input line 7.

But the sub-preamble obviously didn't change. Do you understand what happens?

## Edit

### New MCE in order to clarify my question.

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{subfile1.tex}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Content's~of~\texttt{subfile1.tex}.\par
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{subfile2.tex}
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\foo}{}
\begin{document}
Content's~of~\texttt{subfile2.tex}.\par
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{myclass.cls}
\ProvidesExplClass
  {myclass}
  {2023-01-03}
  {0.1}
  {
    My Nice Class
  }
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\LoadClass { article }
%
\RequirePackage[subpreambles]{standalone}
%
\NewDocumentCommand{\myinput}{ m }
{
  \input{#1}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\myfileinput}{ m }
{
  \file_input:n{#1}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{myclass}
\begin{document}
\myinput{subfile1}
\myinput{subfile2}
\myfileinput{subfile1}
\myfileinput{subfile2}
\end{document}
```

### Original MCE:

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{subfile1.tex}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Content's~of~\texttt{subfile1.tex}.\par
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{subfile2.tex}
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\foo}{}
\begin{document}
Content's~of~\texttt{subfile2.tex}.\par
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[subpreambles]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\input{subfile1}
\input{subfile2}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\file_input:n{subfile1}
\file_input:n{subfile2}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Comment: you are reading the files with expl3 catcodes, so spaces are different and the comparision fails.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Is there a workaround?

Comment: I doubt it. This subpreambles stuff looks quite fragile, e.g. hyperref errors as it is loaded to late, and babel/french can affect catcodes too.

Comment: You should refrain from using \ExplSyntaxOn/Off as part of your document. It is intended to enable defining stuff not "running arbitrary content". Expecting that anything work if you enable \ExplSyntaxOn and then pass it arbitrary stuff is nearly ever going to work.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach Using `\ExplSyntaxOn`/`Off` as part of my document was just for the MCE. I first encountered the problem in a personal class coded in `expl3`. Should I draw the attention of the `standalone` author, or is it hopeless to make his package work with `\file_input:n`?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé your question is not clear the file inputs that `standalone` worries about are always in the main document aren't they? so should not be in the scope of `\ExplSyntaxOn` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've edited my question with a new MCE which, hopefully, make clearer my question.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé I misread your edit and made and deleted a comment, I'll check later

Comment: sorry I was wrong: the problem are not (only) catcodes but also the input command: standalone relies (through the currfile package) on the latex file hooks to get the names of the files. So the expl3 command can't work, you need \input.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Is it worth to report to `currfile`'s author?

Comment: no. there is imho nothing sensible he can or should do. If you want to make use of the extended options from the file hooks (and your example is doing that) then use a command which offers file hooks, and that means \input or \include and not `\file_input:n` or `\@@input`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Currently, `ltfilehook` documentation says “There are four hooks that are called for each file that is read using document-level commands such as `\input`, `\include`, `\usepackage`, etc. They are not called for files read using internal low-level methods, such as `\@input` or `\openin`.”. Is it worth to ask to add “or `\file_input:n`”?

Comment: I doubt it. But why do you want so eagerly use the expl3 command?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer In order to not be old fashioned :) More seriously, I thought that 1) using as much as possible `expl3` commands was recommended, 2) `\file_input:n` worked as `\input` (and that's the reason I “reported” here).