# Error when \tcbuselibrary only in the preamble of a standalone subfile

Tags: hyperref, tcolorbox, standalone

The following MCE:

```
% Subfile
%%%%%%%%%
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{subfile.tex}
\documentclass{article}
\tcbuselibrary{documentation}
\begin{document}
Foo.
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}

% Main file
%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[subpreambles]{standalone}
%
\tcbuselibrary{documentation} % ← To be removed 
%
\begin{document}
\input{subfile}
\end{document}
```

compiles like a charm, except if `\tcbuselibrary{documentation}` is removed from the main file (compile at least twice). The errors are:

> ! LaTeX hooks Error: Sorting rule for 'begindocument' hook applied too late.
> (hooks)              Try setting this rule earlier.
>
> For immediate help type H .
> ...
>
> l.421 ...begindocument}{showkeys}{before}{nameref}

and, later:

> ! Undefined control sequence.
>  \csname tcb@doc@index@\idx@format
> \endcsname \hypersetup { citeco...
> l.237 }}
>
> ?
> ! Undefined control sequence.
>  \kvtcb@colhyper
>
> l.237 }}

I'm aware of the Ulrike's warning:

> This subpreambles stuff looks quite fragile, e.g. hyperref errors as it is loaded to late, [...]

in [standalone package wrongly claims sub-preamble of a subfile changed if used with \file_input:n instead of \input](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/670400/18401) but do you understand what's going on and how to fix this issue?

Comment: well exactly my comment. nameref contains a rule to sort code in begindocument, and if nameref (or hyperref) is loaded to late it will error because this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `standalone` package option `subpreambles` is set, sub-preambles are first collected in `.sta` file, then loaded at begin of document (`\AtBeginDocument`). But in general loading packages in `\AtBeginDocument` is not a good idea, see previous discussions in issue [latex3/hyperref#242](https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/242).

I've reported this to `standalone` (see issue [MartinScharrer/standalone#3](https://github.com/MartinScharrer/standalone/issues/3)) and suggested to use `\AddToHook{begindocument/before}` instead.

Below is a workaround. It uses internal, implementation-specific info that `\RemoveFromHook{<hook>}[<label>]` will globally store the removed code in `\l__hook_return_tl`.

```tex
% Subfile
%%%%%%%%%
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{subfile.tex}
\documentclass{article}
\tcbuselibrary{documentation}
\begin{document}
Foo.
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}

% Main file
%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[subpreambles]{standalone}

% move standalone code in hook `begindocument` to `begindocument/before`
\RemoveFromHook{begindocument}[standalone]
\ExpandArgs{nv}\AddToHook{begindocument/before}{l__hook_return_tl}

%
%\tcbuselibrary{documentation} % ← To be removed
%
\begin{document}
\input{subfile}
\end{document}
```